# What can i do to loop a case structure when the user entered an incorrect value

Tags: java

```
public static int Class() {

     System.out.println("Character Types");

     String []chaName = new String[]{"\tWizard", "\tSorcerer", "\tMonk", "\tCleric", "\tWarlock", 
               "\tDruid", "\tRouge", "\tBard", "\tFighter", "\tRanger", "\tPaladin", "\tBarbarian"}; 
     int []characterDiceValue = new int[]{6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 10, 10, 10, 12};

     Arrays.stream(chaName).forEach(System.out::println);

     System.out.println("Select a Character name from the given list above");
     characterClass = sc.next();

     switch(characterClass) {
     case "Wizard" :
     case "wizard" : hitDice = characterDiceValue[0];
     break;
     case "Sorcerer" :
     case "sorcerer" : hitDice = characterDiceValue[1];
     break;
     case "Monk" :
     case "monk" : hitDice = characterDiceValue[2];
     break;
     case "Cleric" :
     case "cleric" : hitDice = characterDiceValue[3];
     break;
     case "Warlock" :
     case "warlock" : hitDice = characterDiceValue[4];
     break;
     case "Druid" :
     case "druid" : hitDice = characterDiceValue[5];
     break;
     case "Rouge" :
     case "rouge" : hitDice = characterDiceValue[6];
     break;
     case "Bard" :
     case "bard" : hitDice = characterDiceValue[7];
     break;
     case "Fighter" :
     case "fighter" : hitDice = characterDiceValue[8];
     break;
     case "Ranger" :
     case "ranger" : hitDice = characterDiceValue[9];
     break;
     case "Paladin" :
     case "paladin" : hitDice = characterDiceValue[10];
     break;
     case "Barbarian" :
     case "barbarian" : hitDice = characterDiceValue[11];
     break;
     default : System.out.println("Invalid input. Enter again");
     characterClass = sc.next();
     break;
     }   
     return hitDice;

 }
```

Please note that this is just a part of the code. what i need to do is to loop the whole case part when the user entered an invalid input. what is the best method, the while condition or the do while.Additionally i would like to know whether i can shorten this case, as in using any other method rather than using the case.(like use a for loop)

Comment: use a `do while` loop

Comment: I would suggest using a `Map` rather than a `switch`, and using `String.toLowerCase` to remove the noise. Then just wrap the whole lot in a `while(hitDice < 0)` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- To allow the user to make and mistake and ask him again, you can use a `do while` loop, it'll ask first the user, and if the condition still match (input not ok) you can ask again
- you'd better use a `List` to store the names because it'll allows you to find the element and get it's index directly for the array (and if you add more element, you won't have to add several `cases` to your switch
- don't store the `\t` with the name, because it's NOT part of the name, it's part of `printing` so use it at printing time
- *Please* name you `method` following conventions : lowerCamelCase + significant name

---

Here is how you can achieve it, the condition in the while `((index = chaName.indexOf(characterClass)) == -1)` means that if the `index` of the input is `-1` it means not found so not valid, so you'll ask again

```
public static int Class() {
    System.out.println("Character Types");

    List<String> chaName = Arrays.asList("Wizard", "Sorcerer", "Monk", "Cleric", "Warlock",
            "Druid", "Rouge", "Bard", "Fighter", "Ranger", "Paladin", "Barbarian");
    int[] characterDiceValue = new int[]{6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 10, 10, 10, 12};

    chaName.forEach(s -> System.out.println("\t" + s));
    int index = -1;
    String characterClass;

    do {
        System.out.println("Select a Character name from the given list above");
        characterClass = sc.nextLine();
    } while ((index = chaName.indexOf(characterClass)) == -1);

    return characterDiceValue[index];

}
```

---

As second way, using `Map` to store `key/values` elements :

```
public static int Class() {
    System.out.println("Character Types");

    Map<String, Integer> data = new HashMap<>();
    data.put("Wizard", 6);   data.put("Sorcerer", 6);   data.put("Monk", 8);
    data.put("Cleric", 8);   data.put("Warlock", 8);    data.put("Druid", 8);
    data.put("Rouge", 8);    data.put("Bard", 8);       data.put("Fighter", 10);
    data.put("Ranger", 10);  data.put("Paladin", 10);   data.put("Barbarian", 12);

    data.keySet().forEach(s -> System.out.println("\t" + s));
    int value = -1;
    String choice;

    do {
        System.out.println("Select a Character name from the given list above");
        choice = sc.nextLine();
    } while ((value = data.getOrDefault(choice, -1)) == -1);

    return value;
}
```

Comment: Why use parallel collections rather than a `Map`. You've turned the OPs code, which is efficient, into something horrendously inefficient. This is trivial with a `Map` - use one of those, or stick to a `switch`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Yes there may be better ways of doing this. But i'm still a beginner in programming and still in the process of learning java. Like i said this is just part of the code that i'm working on and a lot of improvements are needed to be done. Map is a new concept to me so i'll learn it and use it to improve the code. Thanks for the feedback. I appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

You do not use **case "testval":** twice with each "switch test",
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.